# How to separate values from an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How to separate values from an array using PHP. Following is my code.

```
http://oditek.in/spesh/mobileapi/categoryproduct.php?item=1&acn=5&subcatid=a15,17,19
```

From the above URL I have to extract the `subcatid` value and those are having letter at beginning like `a15` the letter will remove and will remain constant and all id will save into another array.

Comment: Explain more. what exact  you want

Comment: "*Following is my code*" - that's not code - you're just listing data that you want stuff from. What have you tried yourself? If the only thing you've tried it paste the URL into your code and then gave up, then you should do an *actual* try.

Comment: in subcatid i have multiple ids i need to those individually inside a loop and those are having letter with the id in that case letter will remove.By using those ids i need to fetch data from my sql table.

Comment: So you want to save the IDs 15, 17 and 19 per your example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is what you want like this:

```
<?php
$subcatid = explode(",",$_GET['subcatid']);

$arrId = [];
foreach($subcatid AS $id) {
    $arrId[] = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $id);
}

var_dump($arrId);//$arrId contains all the numeric IDs only
?>
```

Comment: You can remove the `,.` in the `preg_replace` if you will just be needing integers. Glad to be of help :)

Comment: @ Jencen : if i wanted to remove values those having letter with number and rest will insert into the array,Then what to do.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not confident that I understood your question. Can you explain thru an example?

Answer (score -1):

Please do it like this:

```
<?php
$subcatids = = explode(",",$_GET['subcatid']);
$new_array = array();

foreach($subcatids as $subcatid) {
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $subcatid, $matches);
    array_push($new_array, $matches[0][0]);
}

print_r($new_array);
?>
```

Comment: its giving the following error output `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/oditek.in/public_html/spesh/mobileapi/categoryproduct.php on line 330
Array ( )`

Comment: $subcatids is not an array